# Error in cv2.cvtColor converting an image to HSV (using cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

Tags: python, opencv, color-conversion

When I open multiple images from a folder and try to convert each into BGR2HSV, I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "create_gestures_manual.py", line 123, in 
> get_img(lab_path)
> File "create_gestures_manual.py", line 114, in get_img
> store_images(g_id, dirr)
> File "create_gestures_manual.py", line 61, in store_images
> imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-wu1ri_rx/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = cv::impl::::NONE; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
>
> > Invalid number of channels in input image:
> > 'VScn::contains(scn)'
> > where
> > 'scn' is 1

Below are snippet of my code:

```
while True:
    framee = cv2.imread(dirr,0)
    img = cv2.flip(framee, 1)
    cv2.imshow('IMG',img)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

**What does this mean?**. Please help me out. And how to solve this

Comment: The error message is clear. You are reading your `frame` in grayscale format here `framee = cv2.imread(dirr,0)` (0 -> grayscale). Remove 0 and try

Comment: Looks like `img` is a single channel (grayscale) image, not bgr/rgb.

Comment: Yeah i given flag 0... Thanks jeru Luke and wohlstad... for coming forward to help me out..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the error is that `framee` is a single channel grayscale image (and so is `img` which is created based on it). It is not a 3 channel color image, and therefore cannot be converted directly to hsv.

As you can see in this link: [**`imread`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), the 2nd parameter `flags` determines the format of the read image.

In your code you use `0`, which internally maps to `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. So even if your image file contains an rgb image, it will be converted to 1 channel grayscale.

Since the default for `flags` is `IMREAD_COLOR`, you can simply use:

```
framee = cv2.imread(dirr)
```

**On a side note:** even if you don't want this default, it's recommended to use the opencv enum values (e.g. `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`) instead of an integer. Doing so you would never encounter this problem.

Comment: Yeah i have given the flag 0.. Now solved.. Thanks for helping me out...!

Answer (score 2):

you read your image as grayscale image.
change this part:

```
framee = cv2.imread(dirr)
```

to have bgr image and then convert bgr to hsv.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and helping me out